# Dynamically setting state object by passing it as variable name : React

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have this scenario where I need to send a list of state object variables, and then dynamically set them inside the setState function by using the passed variable. Trying to achieve the same.
I am maintaining one setState functions, to which I will be passing state variables which are then set accordingly.

Am I going somewhere wrong?

Help would be appreciated.

Relevant snippet has been posted

```
constructor()
{
  super(props);
  this.state ={
      val1 : '',
      val2: '',
      val3: '',
  }
}

fetchValues = (stateVariable) =>{  // here the stateVariable ie val1,val2,val3 will be passed . 

  //fetching a value that will be set to the state object variables   
   this.set(stateVariable,value)
}

set = (val) => {
 this.setState(`${val}`: val
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that this way:

```
const set = val => {
  this.setState({ [val]: val });
};
```

Plus you had issues like:

- There's no `=>` after `(val)`.
- The closing braces aren't right.
- You're missing a `const`.

Fixed everything for you.

Quick demo for you.

```js
var val = "Praveen";

console.log({ [val]: val });
```